# BigQuery - How to set read timeout in the Java client library

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-http-client

I am using Spark to load some data into BigQuery. The idea is to read data from S3 and use Spark and BigQuery client API to load data. Below is the code that does the insert into BigQuery.

```
val bq = createAuthorizedClientWithDefaultCredentialsFromStream(appName, credentialStream)
val bqjob = bq.jobs().insert(pid, job, data).execute() // data is a InputStream content
```

With this approach, I am seeing lot of SocketTimeoutException.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:911)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:703)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1534)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

Looks like the delay in reading from S3 causes Google http-client to timeout. I wanted to increase the timeout and tried the below options.

```
val req = bq.jobs().insert(pid, job, data).buildHttpRequest()
req.setReadTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000)
val res = req.execute()
```

But this causes a Precondition failure in BigQuery. It expects the mediaUploader to be null, not sure why though.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:297)
```

This caused me to try the second insert API on BigQuery

```
val req = bq.jobs().insert(pid, job).buildHttpRequest().setReadTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000).setContent(data)
val res = req.execute()
```

And this time it failed with a different error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0: ",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0: "
}
```

Please suggest me how I can set the timeout. Also point me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this entirely. A couple questions: (1) If the problem is that the S3 read is slow, can you read the S3 content first, and then fire of the BigQuery operation after you have the data locally? BigQuery doesn't support reading directly from S3, so you must be transferring the content locally. (2) Can you give an example of the job request json that is timing out?

Comment: Regarding the last issue you mention, "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object, but there were 0", you are throwing away the original configuration and then sending an empty json request to bigquery.jobs.insert. I think this will be fixed by setting the timeout correctly -- see answer below for how to do this.

Comment: you should try Google Storage Transfer API - https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/index. S3 is claimed to be supported as a source while gcs as a destination

Comment: @MichaelSheldon I cannot read the content first and then try as I have around 100 million records per day. So currently we give the S3 location to Spark, read the files in parallel, partition it and for each partition create an InputStream and hand that to the BigQuery insert job. I will see if I can share a request json. And thanks for your comment on the other error.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant As of now, we do not want to go with GCS. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the main question from the title: how to set timeouts using the Java client library.

To set timeouts, you need a custom HttpRequestInitializer configured in your client. For example:

```
Bigquery.Builder builder =
    new Bigquery.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential);
final HttpRequestInitializer existing = builder.getHttpRequestInitializer();
builder.setHttpRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
      existing.initialize(request);
      request
          .setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT)
          .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
      }
    });
Bigquery client = builder.build();
```

I don't think this will solve all the issues you are facing. A few ideas that might be helpful, but I don't fully understand the scenario so these may be off track:

- If you are moving large files: consider staging them on GCS before loading them into BigQuery.
- If you are using media upload to send the data with your request: these can't be too large or you risk timeouts or network connection failures.
- If you are running an embarrassingly parallel data migration, and the data chunks are relatively small, `bigquery.tabledata.insertAll` may be more appropriate for large fan-in scenarios like this. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery for more details.

Thanks for the question!

Comment: Thanks Michael for your valuable inputs. I will try this and update. And using a Streaming API for a batch operation did not look right to me. Especially with lot of data, I think it would make sense to use the batch load like insert API.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. It still times out with 20secs though I have set a higher time out. I am now wondering if I am going in the right direction. Are there any other options for the use case of loading records from lot of files in a storage other than gcs?